# Block processing patterns of gpu cards using their SM cores

Tags: cuda, nvidia, multiprocessor

I have a question about the scheduling processes of compute capability 1.3 and 2.0 gpu cards.
The maximum blocks scheduled each time at a Streaming Multiprocessor are 8 in both cases, at least that's what I have noticed from the Occupancy Calculator.

At a 1.3 card each SM has 8 cores and at a 2.0 card there are 32 cores per SM.
How are the cores distributed for a block process?

For the 1.3 does each core process 1 block? And if so, if there are less than 8 blocks per SM then more cores than one are assigned to process a block?

For the 2.0 if 8 blocks are scheduled in a SM then are 4 cores assigned to process a block? If there are less blocks in a SM then more cores are scheduled for a block calculation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

All cores in a single SM work in lockstep (at least up to cc 2.0).  When the threads associated with a single lockstep warp hit a stall for some reason, the scheduler will bring another warp in, if it is ready to run.  The new warp may be from the same or a different threadblock, ie. from amongst the up to 8 threadblocks that may be currently resident on that SM.

You may be interested in reading [this section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#hardware-implementation) of the programming guide.